# value_if - the converse of value_or for std::optional?

Tags: semantics, option-type, c++17, algebraic-data-types

`std::optional` has the method

```
template< class U > constexpr T value_or( U&& default_value ) const&;
```

and yet, it doesn't have the constructor

```
template< class U > optional(bool condition, const U& value );
```

which seeps like the opposite thing. Alternatively, you would expect it to have the static method / named constructor idiom:

```
constexpr std::optional<T> value_if(bool condition, const T& value) {
    return condition ? nullopt : std::optional(value);
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there a conceptual problem with a `value_if` (in either of the variants I listed)?
2. Was something like that proposed to go into the standard?

Note: I wasn't sure whether to have `const T& value` or `const T&& value`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a conceptual problem with a value_if (in either of the variants I listed)?

Yes. It requires that you create a live `T` object, even if your condition is creating a `nullopt`. Whereas doing `auto t = cond ? optional<T>(expr) : nullopt;` inline will only evaluate `expr` if `cond` is `true`.

For example:

```
auto optStr1 = value_if(cond, get_object(...)); //Will *always* evaluate get_object
auto optStr2 = cond ? optional(get_object(...)) : nullopt; //Will only evaluate get_object if `cond` is true
```

> Was something like that proposed to go into the standard?

No.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. At which point will a live T object be created, if I pass by reference? I mean, there's the initial argument I pass to `value_if`, which is an existing object I pass a reference to; and there's the construction in the third clause of the trinary operator - but it's short-circuilt logic, so that doesn't actually get called. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @einpoklum: See the added examples.

Comment: Ah, but that's exactly the same as `my_optional.value_or(get_object(...))` , which could be replaced with `auto v = my_optional ? my_optional.value : v{}`;

Comment: @einpoklum: I don't think there's any reason for one over the other, except for user expectations. `value_or` is a nice convenience function that many users expect. A constructor to compliment that apparently isn't that expected.